# Are there geographical restrictions to the software center?

Tags: 11.04, software-center, paid-applications

I am not able to see even a single application for purchase in Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal Software Center. It has been the like this ever since i did clean install over 10.10.

Are available applications restricted to geographic boundaries? I live in India.

How many apps can you see on your computer? Can someone guide me into getting this feature in back in the Software Center?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I do have the Partner, Universe, Multiverse, Restricted, and even "Independent" repositories enabled. I currently use the Main Ubuntu server to fetch updates. Can anyone single-down onto the repository that provides the applications for purchase

Answer (score 1):

I live in India and I've set my update server to default ubuntu server. This is how it looks :

[image: Ubuntu software cener]

Try changing your update server and see if that helps. I've found that the IIT-M server (which I used for a bit) [is heavily behind](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors). However, I haven't gone back to it and have relied on the main servers since then.

Comment: Even I've set my update servers to the default repository. In spite of that, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I live in Germany and my Software center looks like:

[image]

Too few apps in my opinion.

Comment: I see the same in the US.

Comment: What active repositories do you guys have? Apart from ppa-s and third party repositories